# Como faço para percorrer um Array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como faço para percorrer um `Array` e retornar o valor dele.

No caso, seria para comparar se uma palavra/letra digitada num `input` já foi inserida antes por outro `input` e, se foi, ela teria que ser removida.

Comment: [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while), [`Array.protorype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), veja se algum lhe serve.

Comment: Não sei o que isso tem a ver com orientação a objetos

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai um exemplo usando o includes para verificar se existe ou nao o valor no array.

Outros :

[W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Exemplo usando forEach :

[W3 FOREACH](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach)

```js
var palavras = ["mateus", "veloso", "vermelho"];
$(function(){
  $('#bt').click(function(){
    let valor = $('#teste').val();
    if(palavras.includes(valor)){
      alert('palavra encontrada no array');
    }else{
      alert('palavra não encontrada no array');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="teste">
<input type="button" value="verificar" id="bt">
```